# perl timeout when downloading file from ftp

Tags: perl, ftp

I try to download huge file which takes a lot of time downloading from ftp link using perl.
I got:

```
Timeout at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/Net/FTP.pm
```

what does this means and how to solve it?

Thanks

**Solution:**
Thanks @Chris Doyle 
I change the timeout value in my perl file `"not ftp.pm file"`
Thanks

Comment: What have you done to try to solve the problem yourself? Have you looked at the Net::FTP documentation, perhaps searching for "timeout"? http://search.cpan.org/~shay/libnet-3.08/lib/Net/FTP.pm

Comment: if you look at the documentation for the word timeout the first thing you see is `Timeout - Set a timeout value in seconds (defaults to 120)` so if file is taking longer than 120 seconds to download then you need to change the timeout value before starting the ftp

Comment: @Mort I open ftp.pm in my computer and look for timout variable it written as: 'Timeout   => $ftp->timeout' I want to know how to change it "the syntax? and what is the suggested value. I don't want to play in something I don't understand.

Comment: @Chris Doyle I open ftp.pm in my computer and look for timout variable it written as: 'Timeout => $ftp->timeout' I want to know how to change it "the syntax? and what is the suggested value. I don't want to play in something I don't understand.

Comment: you set it as part of the creating of the ftp object. i would suggest you show your code if you want people to help, you should not be changing the ftp.pm module its self. the module allows you to specify a timeout value from your own code

Comment: @Chris Doyle my code is in php and it just call perl file

Comment: @Chris Doyle I see it. I see in the called perl file, there is: my $opt_timeout = 120; Oooooh. I did not wrote the perl file. I use it from some source. thanks a lot. I can change it now. what do you suggest a value? I want a very higher one.

Comment: then show how you call it. there will have to be some line of perl code that loads the FTP module. Normally in perl code it would be something like `my $ftp = Net::FTP->new("localhost", Timeout => 600);` here i have set timeout as 600 which will now overwrite the default 120, so you can change timeout value by passing it as an argument to the object when you create it

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the timeout, but it is important that if the timeout is reached again and your server/client are out of sync, it might throw the same error you got the first time, again.

It seems that the issue is due a lack of error handling in your Perl Script instead.

Surely you have something like this at your perl script:

```
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new( $myhost, Timeout => 10, Debug => 1 );
...
$ftp->get($myfile) or print "Got an error";
$ftp->quit();
```

> Please notice this is out of **.../perl/lib/Net/FTP.pm**, since the
>   FTP.pm is the third party module (`Kind of library`) you are using to
>   reach the ftp, I suggest you to not touch it to avoid portability
>   issues later  on.

Normally the timeout is reached inside the FTP.pm and it goes to the *or print "Got an error"* condition, but there are some cases, that the Server/Client just get out of sync and the FTP.pm just throws an unhandled exception.

This exception will **NOT** go to the *or print "Got an error"* condition, therefore you need to catch it and handle it as any other languages.

Here you can use [eval](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=eval) to wrap it up the code, catch the exception and handle it as you need.

For example:

```
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new( $myhost, Timeout => 10, Debug => 1 );
...
eval {$ftp->get($myfile) or print("Can't get file $myfile") };
if ($@ =~ /Timeout/) {
    print "Got a timeout Issue: $@";
}

$ftp->quit();
```